# Handlebars templates used as client and server side partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, handlebars.js

is possible to render an erb template to HTML in the server side and to handlebars in the client side?

Answer (score 0):

As I see, handlebars extends the Mustache templates, so maybe [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/295-sharing-mustache-templates) railscast by Ryan Bates should be helpful for you.